# is PIN To PIN matching mcu against Atmega328P-AU available?

Tags: arduino-uno, memory

I want to upgrade my product which is based on Atmega328p-AU, having the problem of programming memory. I don't want to change the PCB of the product. Is PIN To PIN matching MCU against Atmega328P-AU available?

Comment: Too little RAM, or too little Flash memory?

Answer (score 2):

The only other AVR chip with more program memory in the 32/TQFP form factor is the [ATMEGA4808](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATMEGA4808) at 48 kB.

Unfortunately, the pinout is not the same compared to the ATMEGA328P-AU:

[ATMEGAx8P family datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf)

[ATMEGAx08 family datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/32-pin-Data-Sheet-megaAVR-0-series-DS40002017B.pdf)